# Count number of shared users to the given file in django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

I have a table called share like this:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
| id | users_id | files_id | shared_user_id | shared_date                      |
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
|  2 |        1 |        2 |              2 | 2013-03-13 20:33:36.766030+00:00 |
|  4 |        1 |        4 |              2 | 2013-03-13 20:33:36.766030+00:00 |
|  5 |        1 |        5 |              2 | 2013-03-13 20:33:36.766030+00:00 |
|  6 |        1 |        6 |              2 | 2013-03-13 20:33:36.766030+00:00 |
|  8 |        1 |        2 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 10 |        1 |        4 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 11 |        1 |        5 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 12 |        1 |        6 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 13 |        1 |        7 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 14 |        1 |        8 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 15 |        1 |        9 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 16 |        1 |       12 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:15:29.580095+00:00 |
| 18 |        1 |        2 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 20 |        1 |        4 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 21 |        1 |        5 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 22 |        1 |        6 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 23 |        1 |        7 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 24 |        1 |        8 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 25 |        1 |        9 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 26 |        1 |       12 |              2 | 2013-03-14 16:17:57.929392+00:00 |
| 27 |        1 |       12 |              2 | 2013-03-15 15:51:50.344222+00:00 |
| 28 |        1 |        9 |              3 | 2013-03-15 15:58:06.655270+00:00 |
| 29 |        1 |        2 |              2 | 2013-03-15 15:59:58.023322+00:00 |
+----+----------+----------+----------------+----------------------------------+
```

I want to find out the total number of users the file is shared for each `files_id`. How can I do that?

Tried this:

```
Share.objects.filter(users_id=request.user.id).values_list('shared_user_id', flat=True).distinct()
```

But this counts only the `shared_user_id`.

Here are my models:

```
class Share(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    files = models.ForeignKey(File)
    shared_user_id = models.IntegerField()
    shared_date = models.TextField()

class File(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.TextField()
    time_overview = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    end_date = models.TextField()
    duration = models.TextField()
    size_overview = models.IntegerField()
    size = models.TextField()
    flag = models.TextField()
    flag_r = models.TextField()
```

Comment: i dont know how to do it in django but put a group by clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple query to count in mysql

```
SELECT
    files_id,
    count(shared_user_id) AS `Shared`
FROM mytable
GROUP BY files_id
ORDER BY files_id
```

Comment: Also why would I want to count the users_id. I want to count shared_user_id.

Comment: @user2032220 if you want the django way, pls remove `mysql` tag from the question.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Django's [Aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) functionality.

Using your models, you could do:

```
counts = Share.objects.all().annotate(num_shares=Count("shared_user_id"))
for count in counts:
    print "%s - %s shares" % (count.files, count.num_shares)
```

To get the counts for a specific file, assuming `file` is an object representing a given file:

```
count = Share.objects.filter(files=file).annotate(num_shares=Count("shared_user_id"))
print count[0].num_count
```

Comment: What is file.id? What is num_shared? See my updated question with models.

Comment: Using your below query I get the following error: Required argument 'name' (pos 1) not found

Comment: See my updated question which consist of the file model. THanks

Comment: And, if I do file = Share.objects.filter(users_id=request.user.id) I get Subquery returns more than one row.